# Using Git to create a 2-way remote Subversion branch

Tags: git, svn, tfs

My client has a Subversion repository at `https://mysvnurl/repo`.

I wish to work on a new feature in parallel to their work in the repo, which will later need to be merged back into their Subversion trunk.

For various technical reasons, they cannot create a branch on their repo for me to work on and commit to, so Git seems to be a good choice using its interoperability with Subversion.

I also need other devs to work on the new feature so need to host the Git repo somewhere.

TortoiseGit allows easy cloning from Subversion so I went down that path, but after experimenting with it, I'm unsure exactly if it meets my requirements.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Used TortoiseGit to clone an SVN repo at the latest revision to a local Git repo. This has created a git repo and checked out a working copy for me. It has also added an `svn-remote` in the `.git/config` file pointing to the svn repo and some other bits into `.git/svn`.
2. Added my TFS-hosted Git repo as a remote origin using `git remote add origin <my tfs git repo url>`
3. I've pushed using `git push -u origin --all`.

This seems to have worked, but when other devs clone the Git repo on TFS, they no longer have an svn-remote entry in their Git config, and I'm concerned that the link back to the original Subversion repo has been lost.

Can someone let me know if devs can just add this remote locally and maintain the link back to Subversion for subsequent commits (using `git dcommit`?)?

Thank you.

Comment: You can test your scenario by locally setting up SVN and Git repositories and trying it out.